# sorting array with date in string without comparator

Tags: ios6

everyone
I am in another mess. I need to sort an array with date in strings and names corresponding to their birthday (date).And then view it in table view. Is there any way?

Comment: Why dont you want to use comparator? It is a very easy and powerful way.

Comment: You should store data in the most appropriate data type, which would be `NSDate` in this case.  This problem would then become trivial.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd"];

```
sortedDataSource = [BdayArr sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *obj1, NSDictionary *obj2) {
    NSDate *d1 = [formatter dateFromString:obj1[kKeyDOB]];
    NSDate *d2 = [formatter dateFromString:obj2[kKeyDOB]];

    return [d1 compare:d2]; // ascending order
    //return [d2 compare:d1]; // descending order
}];

NSLog(@"%@",sortedDataSource);
}
```

Comment: Poor solution as there is excessive conversion to `NSDate`.  Why not keep a list of `NSDate` objects in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to sort by birthday. And make Conditions as per your requirements.

```
-(void)sortAllDate:(NSMutableArray *)arrayToSort
    {
        NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"self"
                                                                   ascending:YES];
        NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor];
        NSArray *reverseOrder = [arrayToSort sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];

        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];

        NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (int k=0; k<[reverseOrder count]; k++) {

            for(int m=0;m<[frdArray count];m++)
            {
                NSString *dateStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[frdArray objectAtIndex:m] birthday]];
                if([dateStr isEqualToString:[formatter stringFromDate:[reverseOrder objectAtIndex:k]]])
                {

                    [temp addObject:[frdArray objectAtIndex:m]];
                }
            }
        }

        frdArray = temp;

    }
```

Comment: You remove all objects from the final array and then re-assign it?  Why not just do `frdArray = temp;`?

Comment: @Droppy.. I have some other code also for that reason which I have not write here because there is no need to answer the question.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  Those two statements are sub-optimal and should be changed.

Comment: Okay.. I will.. Tell me the reason. The major difference?

Comment: Well you remove objects from an array that is about to be destroyed and you create the new array using `initWithArray` when you may as well simply assign the temporary array.  The code will be both shorter and quicker.